# Tristate checkbox: deny user from setting it to PartiallyChecked

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I have tristate checkbox. I want to be able to set it to Qt.PartiallyChecked from my code, but I do NOT want the user to be able to set it to this state.

This is the workaround I use now:

```
CheckBox
{
     checkState: allCheckState
     tristate: true
     onClicked: {
          if (checkState == Qt.PartiallyChecked)
               checkState = Qt.Checked;
     }
}
```

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the [`nextCheckState`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-checkbox.html#nextCheckState-prop) function. Quoting the documentation:

> This property holds a callback function that is called to determine
>   the next check state whenever the checkbox is interactively toggled by
>   the user via touch, mouse, or keyboard.
>
> By default, a normal checkbox cycles between Qt.Unchecked and
>   Qt.Checked states, and a tri-state checkbox cycles between
>   Qt.Unchecked, Qt.PartiallyChecked, and Qt.Checked states.
>
> The nextCheckState callback function can override the default
>   behavior. The following example implements a tri-state checkbox that
>   can present a partially checked state depending on external
>   conditions, but never cycles to the partially checked state when
>   interactively toggled by the user.
>
> ```
> CheckBox {
>     tristate: true
>     checkState: allChildrenChecked ? Qt.Checked :
>                    anyChildChecked ? Qt.PartiallyChecked : Qt.Unchecked
>
>     nextCheckState: function() {
>         if (checkState === Qt.Checked)
>             return Qt.Unchecked
>         else
>             return Qt.Checked
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> This QML property was introduced in QtQuick.Controls 2.4 (Qt 5.11).